# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: model.byid is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Im so frustrated with this error.. before i add some file to my project, my passport works well.. but after i add some file(like controller, view) it always show this error..

here my code in passport :

```
var passport = require('passport')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const model = require('../models/model_auth')

...

passport.deserializeUser(async function (req, data, done) {
    var [resFind, errFind] = await model.byid(data.id);
    if (errFind) return done(null, false);

    console.log('deserialize user: ',data.id)
    done(null, data);
});
```

here my model_auth :

```
const mysql = require('../module/mysql_connector')
const passport = require('../module/passport')
module.exports ={
...
byid: async function(id_panel_users){
        try{
            await mysql.connectAsync()
            var sql= "SELECT * FROM ms_users WHERE id_user="+id_panel_users+" ";
            var [result,cache]= await mysql.queryAsync(sql)
            await mysql.endPool()
            return [result, null]
        }catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            await mysql.endPool()
            return [null, error]
        }
    },
}
```

here the error :

Example app listening on port 3000
(node:10700) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: model.byid is not a function
    at D:\magang\eweekly\app\module\passport.js:15:46
    at pass (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:355:9)
    at Authenticator.deserializeUser (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:362:5)
    at SessionStrategy.authenticate (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\passport\lib\strategies\session.js:60:10)
    at attempt (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:366:16)
    at authenticate (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:367:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\magang\eweekly\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)

so whats wrong with my model or passport?? before i added files it works! :"

Comment: what does file '../models/model_auth' contains?

Comment: @Yevhenii its only a sql functions..

Comment: without content of that file i can't help you resolve this. I think error comes from here. Could you add it in question's body?

Comment: i already added some code of that file @Yevhenii

Comment: try realize what your `model` contains. Execute this code and show result of it `const model = require('../models/model_auth'); console.log(model);`.

Comment: its {}.. whats happen with my model.. @Yevhenii

Comment: weird... make sure that all paths is correct and no code don't reassign/rewrite or other kind of object modification for your object